# defining sdl_rect and sdl_mousebuttondown

Tags: c, sdl

I need to define **rectangular areas** on the **sdl window** so that when the mouse button is clicked on a particular area some action has to be performed.

I used `GetMouseState(x,y)` to get the mouse click event. It works wherever the mouse button is clicked. But rather i need to get the mouse x and y and check it with sdl rect x and y to c if whether the rectangle is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

There actually is a built-in function for that called `SDL_PointInRect`. It returns true if clicked and false otherwise

It takes `SDL_Point*` and `SDL_Rect*` as arguments

```cpp
SDL_Point mousePosition;

// Mouse click coords from event handler
mousePosition.x = event.motion.x; 
mousePosition.y = event.motion.y;

if (SDL_PointInRect(&mousePosition, &someSDL_Rect)) {
    // Do something
}
```

If you look into the header file, this function is very similar to @Alink s answer

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you create a `SDL_Rect` structure containing the rectangle you want. When you get the coordinates of a mouse-click it's very simple to compare it with the rectangle coordinates:

```
/* Function to check if a coordinate (x, y) is inside a rectangle */
int check_click_in_rect(int x, int y, struct SDL_Rect *rect)
{
    /* Check X coordinate is within rectangle range */
    if (x >= rect->x && x < (rect->x + rect->w))
    {
        /* Check Y coordinate is within rectangle range */
        if (y >= rect->y && y < (rect->y + rect->h))
        {
            /* X and Y is inside the rectangle */
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* X or Y is outside the rectangle */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be  x < (rect->x + rect->w) and same for y.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version. Note the use of strict inequality for width and height. I also prefer to visualize the 2 corners, instead of as 2 intervals.

```
int in_rect(int x, int y, struct SDL_Rect *r) {
    return (x >= r->x) && (y >= r->y) &&
           (x < r->x + r->w) && (y < r->y + r->h);
}
```